# Kotlin "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders. "

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I want to set texts: Station 1, Station 2, Station 3...

If I have code like this (frame is of type ScrollView) I get the warning: "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders."

```
for(i in 1..10){
    frame.stationTextView.text = "Station $i"
}
```

If, however I do this, I don't get the warning.

```
for(i in 1..10){
    val str = "Station $i"
    frame.stationTextView.text = str
}
```

The second example seems redundant to me, but the warning is gone. Which one is correct, probably neither. I'm not sure how to use resource string with index that is changing.

Comment: The second way is still "wrong". The Linter just isn't sophisticated enough to catch it and warn you about it. It's telling you not to display hard-coded text instead of using proper string resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a string resource like following

```
 <string name="station_counter_text">Station %1$d</string>
```

Then from Activity/Fragment use like following

```
for(i in 1..10)
 frame.stationTextView.text = getString(R.string. station_counter_text,i)
```